# Getting "CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database" " Error on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, cocoapods, geofire

i have followed an exact guide on how to setup a geofire on to my project. i have success on my android project.. but i cant get it to run for the ios.. and it has the following error as i try to run it.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 6.1.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 7.11.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
        Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)
```

I've tried to run `pod update` and this is the result

```
Macbook-MBP:ios Macbook$ pod update
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '7.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '7.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '7.11.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to                             
    6.1.2, which depends on Firebase/Database (= 7.11.0)

    flutter_geofire (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_geofire/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1,
     which depends on
  GeoFire (~> 4.0) was resolved to 4.1.0, which depends on
    Firebase/Database (~> 6.0)
```

and this is what i've imported to my pubspec.yaml file..

```
  firebase_database: ^6.1.2
  flutter_geofire: ^2.0.0
```

i dont understand what im doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for anyone that is facing this issue,

1. run `flutter clean` in the terminal
2. add this line at the bottom of the podfile
   `pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/mrdishant/geofire-objc', :tag => '4.3.0'`
3. dont forget to add `use_frameworks!` on top of the podfile
4. delete Pod folder from iOS.
5. change `platform :ios, '10.0'` to `platform :ios, '11.0'` on the podfile
6. run `pod repo update` then `pod update`
7. then run `flutter run` in the terminal

thats how i got it working for me

Answer (score 1):

Updating the platform configured in the Podfile to `platform :ios, '10.0'` didn't work for me. I've had to update the iOS Deployment Target to 10.0 - located on `Runner > Info > Deployment Target`

[image: Xcode iOS Deployment Target]

After that, deleting the Podfile.lock with `rm -rf Podfile.lock` then running `pod update` and `pod install` solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same challenge but all of the above solutions didn't work for me.
What worked for me:

1. Following the link shown in the error (I've highlighted):
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22l7T.png)
2. In you IDE, go to Project File -> ios -> .symlinks -> plugins -> firebase_database -> ios
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxkOL.png)
3. Open the .podspec file of the dependency.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwwIt.png)
4. Look for: s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
5. I think the "s.ios.deployment_target" should be less than or equal to the "platform :ios, 'XX.0'" in the Podfile.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZweo.png)
6. After changing s.ios.deployment_target value to less than in the platform :ios, in the podfile, try removing Podfile.lock, pod install --repo-update etc.
7. Do the same for other podfiles throwing the error, in your case: flutter_geofire, firebase_database etc.
8. You can check this solution too. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65881232/specs-satisfying-the-firebase-admob-but-they-required-a-higher-minimum-deploy]

Answer (score 0):

copy and replace your file with below codes.
It should works.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/mrdishant/geofire-objc'

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
1 - flutter clean
2 - flutter run